# Is the nonnegativeness of a polynomial hard for $\mathsf{NP}_\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis, computing-over-reals

It is clear that the following problem is in $\mathsf{NP}_\mathbb{R}$.

**Input:** a list $P$ of triplets $(a,s,t)$
where $s$ and $t$ are nonnegative integers.
**Output:** is there an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$p(x) =\sum_{(a,s,t) \in P} a x^s(1-x)^t \geq 0?$$

Is this problem $\mathsf{NP}_\mathbb{R}$-hard?

Comment: The question is essentially if the given $-p(x)$ is _not_ always positive so [Positivstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stengle's_Positivstellensatz) might be related.